# Is non-emptiness equivalent to an equation in ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

That a set has no members can be expressed as an equation, like so: $x = \emptyset$. However, is there a single equation that can express the non-emptiness of a set? I don't mean the negation of a equation, I mean a plain, unnegated equation. Of course, this question is a bit imprecise. Perhaps this is a way of making it more precise: Is there some definitional extension by functions and/or constants of ZFC such that non-emptiness of a set is equivalent to a single equation in that definitional extension?

Comment: Ah, I see, I didn't read the question properly. If we extend ZFC with a symbol $Y^X$ denoting the set of functions $X \to Y$ then non-emptiness of a set $X$ is equivalent to $\emptyset^X = \emptyset$; would that qualify?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, that would qualify, and it is actually better than Noah Schweber's answer.

Comment: I don't know what the details are of making sure that this symbol means what it's supposed to but maybe reading about ETCS could be helpful: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure: the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x & \mbox{ if }x\not=\emptyset\\
\{x\} & \mbox{ if }x=\emptyset\\
\end{cases}$$

is definable in an obvious way, so we can add a symbol for it as an expansion by definitions in any model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. But then nonemptiness is characterized by the equation $$x=f(x).$$ More generally, **every** property is "equational in an expansion by definitions" in exactly the same way.